# React app Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../bugControler'

Tags: javascript

I got this problem when I started my react file
`import bugModel from '../Models/bugModel'`

```js
export function retrieveBugs(){
    let data = [];

    data.push(new bugModel({
        _id: 23456789,
        name: "Crash on Load",
        details:"Crashes after 3 seconds",
        step:"Open application and it will crash",
        version:"V2.0",
        assigned:"Ryan Beasley",
        creator:"Hanna Noskova",
        priority:1,
        time:"16:17",
    }))
    data.push(new bugModel({
        _id: 23456789,
        name: "Wont Load",
        details:"Crashes after 3 seconds",
        step:"Open application and it will crash",
        version:"V2.0",
        assigned:"Ryan Beasley",
        creator:"Hanna Noskova",
        priority:3,
        time:"16:17",
    }))

    let sorted = data.sort((a,b)=>{return a.priority-b.priority})
    return sorted;
}
```

I thought that the problem can be in './' and '../' because it is quite simillar. However I checked it and everything seems correct

Answer (score 0):

We have to look at files structure to verify imports. Please provide project repository or file structure tree on diagram.

- `./` refers to current calalog
- `../` refers to one level up catalog

If you are sure about imports, please try to rerun `npm start` script.